# How can I let Apache JMeter use (password protected) keys from a (password protected) jks keystore

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate, password-protection

### Context

I have a **keystore** (`keystore.jks`) that is **protected by a password**.
I can get jmeter to use keys from that store by providing

- `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore`
- `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`

with the appropriate values as long as the keys themselves are not password protected.

However, my particular keystore contains **multiple keys** that each require a **password to retrieve them**.

### How I access the key in plain old Java:

```java
String keyStorePath = "/keystore.jks";
char[] keyStorePassword = "keyStorePassword".toCharArray();

String keyAlias = "keyAlias";
char[] keyPassword= "keyPassword".toCharArray();


KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(keyStorePath )) {
    keyStore.load(is, keyStorePassword);
}

PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, keyPassword);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias);
```

### How would I retrieve and use such keys in JMeter?

That is the question.

JMeter's `Keystore Configuration` does not allow you to specify a key's password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I concluded that this is currently (JMeter 5.0) not possible.

Get jmeter to use certificates from a key store by providing these properties at startup:

- `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore`
- `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`

The certificates inside the store should have the same password as the store, then they are picked up without problems when you use a [Keystore Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) specifying (a variable that holds) the certificate alias.

Answer (score 0):

Convert key and value(.crt) file into single file and use it in Jmeter
Steps

1. Open command prompt
2. Go to the directory where key and values are placed
3. Run below commands

openssl pkcs12 -export -out jmeterkeystore.p12 -inkey your.private.key -in your.certificate

above command create a .p12 type file
4.  Convert .p12 file to jks type, use below command

```
  keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jmeterkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 - 
     destkeystore MY_KEYSTORE.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass changeit
```

5. In jmeter bin folder, open system.properties file and set following properties

   javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/Dev/cer/<JKSfilname.jks>
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=

Done you can now run your script